# How to vertically center text in a table cell with multiple lines?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically center "Apple iPad".

Does someone here knows how to do that?

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \noindent 
    \centering{}
      \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \hline
            \noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
      Modellname & Display-Auflösung \\ ~ & (in Pixel)
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]
      \hline
      Samsung Galaxy SIII & 1280x720
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]         

      Samsung Galaxy SII & 800x480
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

      Apple iPad & 1024x768 (Standard)
      \\ ~ & 2048x1536 (Retina)
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]         

      Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0) & 1280x720
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]         

      Samsung Galaxy Y & 320x240
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]         

      Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc HD & 1280x720
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

      Amazon Kindle Fire & 1024x600
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

      Google Nexus 7 & 1280x800
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]         

      SamsungGalaxy Tab 2 (10.1) & 1280x720
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

      Motorola Droid Razr 4G & 960x540
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]                     
      \hline
      \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [the `multirow` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) which allows you to create cells spanning multiple rows:

[image]

### Notes:

- I also applied `\multirow` to the header of the first column.
- I also replaced the `x` with `\times`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \noindent 
    \centering{}
      \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \hline
            \noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
      \multirow{2}{*}{Modellname} & Display-Auflösung \\ ~ & (in Pixel)
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]
      \hline
      Samsung Galaxy SIII & $1280 \times 720$
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]         

      Samsung Galaxy SII & $800 \times 480$
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

      \multirow{2}{*}{Apple iPad} & $1024 \times 768$ (Standard)
      \\ ~ & $2048 \times 1536$ (Retina)
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]         

      Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0) & $1280 \times 720$
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]         

      Samsung Galaxy Y & $320 \times 240$
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]         

      Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc HD & $1280 \times 720$
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

      Amazon Kindle Fire & $1024 \times 600$
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

      Google Nexus 7 & $1280 \times 800$
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]         

      SamsungGalaxy Tab 2 (10.1) & $1280 \times 720$
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]

      Motorola Droid Razr 4G & $960 \times 540$
            \tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]                     
      \hline
      \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you very much, I really like this community. :]

Comment: Your welcome. I have updated the solution to replace the `x` with `\times`.